# Can you copy a structure via pointer dereference in (Objective) C?

Tags: objective-c, c

According to Crashlytics, this line is causing trouble:

```
// copy preamble data
_preamble = * (ShowMetaHdrPreamble *) [data bytes];
```

_preamble is a ShowMetaHdrPreamble struct.  data is not nil.  I suppose it's possible that data may not always be long enough to fill a ShowMetaHdrPreamble - it looks like that condition isn't tested for.

But my question is about the syntax, which is not something I've really seen in C or Objective C for copying structs.  I'd generally either copy using memcpy() or by casting and copying individual structure members.  Is this a valid way to format the data byte stream and copy it into a structure?

Any ideas on why this line would sometimes cause a crash, or did I already answer that?

(I'm pretty sure that early on in C you couldn't just copy structures using '=', but I see from ANSI C K&R that it is legal these days.)

Comment: Yes, you can make a copy of a struct using `=`, and yes, you should verify that `data.length >= sizeof(ShowMetaHdrPreamble)` before doing the copy. Which is to say that, yes, you answered your own question :)

Comment: Note however, that there could be issues with endianess, sizes, and padding,  depending on the source of the `data`. The question could be improved by including the exact error message from Crashlytics.

Comment: Crashlytics is reporting EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0, which looks to me like reading off the end of the data bytes.  (Actually it looks like reading a nil pointer, but that's explicitly tested for previously, so it can't be that.)

Comment: Even if `data` is not `nil`, `[data bytes]` *will* be `nil` if `data.length == 0`, so a check on the length may be the only thing needed.

Comment: Another potential problem is alignment. If the data object was created from a subrange of another data object, it might be misaligned, in which case the assignment approach may crash on some architectures (although not with those specific crash details, which do indicate a `NULL` dereference). `memcpy()` would work in that case.